# Ignoring file 'google.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: apt, software-sources

When I run `sudo apt-get update` it returns:

[image: show error]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about. .save file is created when you edit files with nano. Somethimes when you force quite the editor save file is left over. When you delete google.list.save.1 it will remove the error  in apt

Comment: rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list.save.1

Comment: can i 
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list ??